# what is the second processor frequency in the Windows System panel?

Tags: cpu, control-panel, turbo-boost

If you go into Windows Control Panel -> System, you will see a description of the system's processor. For example mine is:

Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6300U CPU @ 2.4GHz 2.50 GHz

If I had to guess, I would say that the second number is what Windows thinks the processor's Max Turbo Frequency is. However, this seems wrong because that processor (per Intel) has a Max Turbo Frequency of 3GHz.

Is this number indeed the Max Turbo Frequency? For extra credit, how does Windows obtain this number, and can it vary from the manufacturer's spec for some reason?

Comment: It's the current frequency of the processor

Comment: "how does Windows obtain this number, and can it vary from the manufacturer's spec for some reason?" the CPU broadcasts this information the same way Windows can identity which CPU you have

Comment: I don't think it's the current frequency, because wmic cpu get CurrentClockSpeed shows 2175. MaxClockSpeed is 2501. So weird, MaxClockSpeed and that second number line up with each other, but don't line up with either number from the spec.

Comment: So looking into more, it's the max frequency, and the reason it's lower then 3 GHz is because your CPU cannot boost past that frequency due to thermal throttling.  2.4 GHz is the base frequency and part of the CPU information, it always says, 2.4 Ghz